# Trying to save an Illustrator document to a 20K GIF/JPG

Tags: adobe-illustrator, save, file-size, jpg

I need the file to be exactly 20K. When I save it as JPG, the smallest I can get it is 32K. When I save it to Web, the largest I can get it 2K...is there an in between or a way to save it exactly that I am missing?

Comment: The compression size will vary by pixel content: a 100px white square might be 400bytes, but the same square filled with noise might be 21 *thousand* bytes. GIF also has compression that depends on context (long runs of one color can be compressed quite easily). I am wondering why the odd requirement of precisely 20x1024 bytes.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. It is a logo for a digital magazine...that is their requirement.

Comment: With all possible different compression and downsampling algorithms, file size means exactly *nothing*. And thus it's a weird requirement for a "digital magazine". They must have some rationale to ask for this size; a minimum and maximum number of pixels is the most logical thing to ask for.

Comment: Maybe you misunderstood the requirement as being general for page-load budget rather than *exact*, or an upper size limit with the implication that you should not lose quality to make it unacceptably small.  A jpeg might not be good for a logo anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Save it as a png first, to do the rastwrization and rendering.  Then use software with full control to compress the png into a jpeg, and binary-search the compression values.

I would use ImageMagick for that.